# Can Font Awesome be used with importmaps in Rails 7?

Tags: font-awesome, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm new to Rails 7's importmap and the [documentation says](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails) you can pin a JavaScript module and then import it:

```sh
./bin/importmap pin react react-dom
```

```js
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
```

How would that work with Font Awesome? Font Awesome's documentation says you [should install the package](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages):

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

but then, when it comes to using it, it says:

```html
<script defer src="/your-path-to-fontawesome/js/brands.js"></script>
<script defer src="/your-path-to-fontawesome/js/solid.js"></script>
<script defer src="/your-path-to-fontawesome/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
```

I'm not entirely clear how to translate that to importmap. I tried:

```html
<script defer src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.0.0/js/brands.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.0.0/js/solid.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.0.0/js/fontawesome.js"></script>
```

since the pinning resulted in:

```rb
pin "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.0.0/js/fontawesome.js"
```

but that doesn't work. It fails with this error in the console in the browser:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the "right" way? Are you having a specific problem with using FA? Any way that works is the "right" way.

Comment: @TylerH: well, for example, using an obsolete gem that nobody is maintaining is something that I would say that even if it works, is not the right importmaps way, which would be using the npm package that fontawesome's team mantains. There are many other suboptimal solutions, like manually downloading CSS and putting them in my repo, which would also work, but I would say are not the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: Adding a specific question and details around your specific problem with attempting to use FA7 makes it a much more clear question, thank you; I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 17):

I wrote a [longer piece about this on my blog](https://pablofernandez.tech/2022/03/12/using-font-awesome-6-in-a-rails-7-project-that-uses-importmaps/), but the gist is copied here.

I just made it work but I'm not entirely sure why it works so I would appreciate any insight or improvements on this solution. In the meantime, I'm happy to share with the world:

First, you need to pin the Font Awesome Javascript packages by running:

```sh
./bin/importmap pin @fortawesome/fontawesome-free @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
```

which adds:

```rb
pin "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.0.0/js/fontawesome.js"
pin "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.3.0/index.es.js"
pin "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons@6.0.0/index.es.js"
pin "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons@6.0.0/index.es.js"
pin "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@6.0.0/index.es.js"
```

to your `importmap.rb`.

Then in your `app/javascript/application.js` you need to add:

```js
import {far} from "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons"
import {fas} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
import {fab} from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"
import {library} from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free"
library.add(far, fas, fab)
```

If you don't need one of the libraries you can skip them, but skipping the last two imports or adding each icon package to the library makes it not work.

Answer (score 7):

```rb
# TLDR

# config/importmap.rb
# NOTE: rename `fontawesome.js` to `all.js`
pin "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free",
  to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/all.js"

# app/javascript/application.js
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";
```

---

Based on documentation, we need to load `js/all.js` from fontawesome package to load all icons *https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/svg-js#add-font-awesome-files-to-your-project*.

You must have `javascript_importmap_tags` in your layout for this to work.

Pin `fontawesome`:

```
$ bin/importmap pin @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
Pinning "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/fontawesome.js
```

That command doesn't pin the correct file, so we need to change it:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

# NOTE: change `fontawesome.js` to `all.js`
pin "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free",
  to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/all.js"
```

Import it in *application.js*:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free"; // => https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/all.js
```

Everything should work now.

---

Alternatively, import pinned module in the layout instead of *application.js*:

```rb
<%= javascript_import_module_tag "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free" %>
```

---

To load only certain styles, we need to load `solid.js`, `brands.js`, and `fontawesome.js` separately.

Pin `fontawesome` and don't change it:

```
$ bin/importmap pin @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
Pinning "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/fontawesome.js
```

Pin *solid.js*:

```
$ bin/importmap pin @fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid.js
Pinning "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid.js" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/solid.js
```

Pinned name is a bit verbose, so we could rename it:

```rb
pin "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/solid", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/solid.js"
```

Import it in *application.js*:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js

import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/solid";  // => https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/solid.js
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";        // => https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/fontawesome.js
```

Do the same for *brands.js* if needed.

You should end up with something like this in your rendered layout:

```html
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "application": "/assets/application-66ce7505c61e3e4910ff16e7c220e1fbfb39251cd82e4bab8d325b3aae987cf9.js",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/fontawesome.js",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/solid": "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/js/solid.js",
}</script>

<script type="module">import "application"</script>
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution, I can confirm it works

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the official [FontAwesome Ruby gem](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/ruby-on-rails) which seems to be working well