# Install fontawsome on Rails 7.0.4.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

How can I install fontawsome for icons on `Rails 7.0.4.3` and `ruby 3.2.1`

I tried three methods:

```
1. yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free + import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all"
2. ./bin/importmap pin @fortawesome/fontawesome-free + import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free"
3. gem "font-awesome-sass", "~> 6.3.0" +  bundle install + @import "font-awesome"
```

But when I test with an icon it is not rendering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72148979/207090

Comment: when I added the =  javascript_importmap_tags to views/layouts/application.html.haml the icons did not rendered and bootstrap stopped being dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css`
to my app/views/layouts/_bootstrap_cdn.html.erb file. Not sure if this is the "right" way but it's working for my Rails 7 app.

Comment: thanks @Rebecca, your suggestion worked for me. I added this line in views/layouts/application.html.haml: `%link{:href => "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/`